# JavaScript: returning NaN (Part 2)

Tags: javascript

(note this is similar to but not the same as the question I asked moments ago - the solution to that question was to add the brackets when calling Math.Random)

At the bottom of the code below, I'm dealing out two hands of blackjack `myhand` and `yourhand` and then logging the hands to the console

```
"I scored a "+myHand.score()+" and you scored a "+ yourHand.score());
```

However, the result I'm getting is

```
I scored NaN and you scored a NaN
```

Originally, the getValue method in the Card constructor was passed a parameter called `card` but the instructions for building the Hand constructor said to call getValue without passing a parameter

```
this.card1.getValue();
```

so I changed the getValue method to take the `var number` (which is in the Card constructor)

anyways, to make a long story short, whatever i do, it's printing out

```
I scored NaN and you scored a NaN
```

and I'm not sure exactly where I'm going wrong.

```
// Make your card constructor again here, but make sure to use private
// variables!
function Card(num, suit){
    var number = num; 
    var suits = suit;
    this.getSuit = function(){
        return suits; 
    }; 
    this.getNumber = function(){
        return number; 
    };

    this.getValue = function(number){
        if (number > 10){
            return 10; 
        }else if (number === 1){
            return 11; 
        }else{
            return number; 
        }

    };

}

function Hand(){
    this.card1 = deal(); 
    this.card2 = deal(); 

    this.score = function(){
    var score1 = this.card1.getValue();
    var score2 = this.card2.getValue();
    return score1 + score2;
    };

}

// Make a deal function here.  It should return a new card with a suit
// that is a random number from 1 to 4, and a number that is a random
// number between 1 and 13

var deal = function(){
    var suit = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 + 1);
    var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13 + 1);
    return new Card(number, suit); 
}; 


// examples of the deal function in action

var myHand = new Hand();
var yourHand = new Hand();
console.log("I scored a "+myHand.score()+" and you scored a "+ yourHand.score());
```

Comment: I added [tag:homework] since this sounds like homework to me.  If I'm mistaken, please remove it.

Comment: I'm working through codecademy.com to learn JavaScript...Most of my questions probably sound like homework, because I'm a wet-brained hobbyist programmer trying to teach myself using whatever online resources are available.. i.e. I'm not building real world apps so not asking real world problems

Comment: Should "This lets potential answerers know that they SHOULD guide the student in solving the problem, and SHOULD NOT simply show the complete answer." from the [tag:homework] tag description apply to this question?

Comment: Try stepping through the `score()` function line by line.

Comment: @RaymondChen I would but I'm having problems using Firebug on code in the browser JavaScript console at codecademy.com Should I be able to use Firebug on javascript typed into a browser sandbox/console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `getValue` function is wrong. It should be:

```
this.getValue = function() {
  if( this.number>10) return 10;
  if( this.number==1) return 11;
  return this.number;
}
```

A hint that something was wrong is that you are calling `this.card1.getValue()` with no arguments, whereas you defined `this.getValue(number)` with an argument.

Comment: or `...function() {return this.number == 1? 1 : Math.min(this.number, 10);}`. :-)

Answer (score 1):

When you address card.getValue() it requires some input

```
this.getValue = function(number){
    if (number > 10){
        return 10; 
    }else if (number === 1){
        return 11; 
    }else{
        return number; 
    }

};
```

The function doest not return anything, resulting in a NaN.
To solve this, use this.number instead

Answer (score 1):

Your get value function accepts a `number` argument
    this.getValue = function(number)

But you aren't passing in the value here:

```
var score1 = this.card1.getValue();
var score2 = this.card2.getValue();
```